# Load test data from file Pytest based on env

Tags: python, pytest

So I m loading test data from a different file based on the environment I'm meant to run the tests:

TestData/DevTestData.py contains:

```
data = {"accessToken": "Random Access Token"}
```

Then I have set up in conftest.py file:

To get the CLI parameter:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
parser.addoption('--environment', action='store')
```

Then to load the data I use LazySettings from simple-settings as a fixture:

```
    @pytest.fixture
def testData(request):
    return LazySettings("TestData." + request.config.getoption("--environment") + "TestData")
```

The test class looks like this:

```
class Test_User_Current():

userCurrentFacadeInstance = userCurrentGetAPI_Facade.User_Current_API_Facade()

def test_succesfull_request(self, environmentConfigs, testData):
    self.userCurrentFacadeInstance.getRequest_user_current_API(environmentConfigs, testData).\
        validateSuccessfullStatusCode().\
        validateJsonContents()
```

CLI is:

```
py.test --environment Dev
```

My problem is, I have to pass "testData" for every test method rather then passing it to User_Current_API_Facade()'s constructor, and I cant do that for some reason, if I'm passing it to the constructor and not the test method (test_succesfull_request()) it does not work.

Do you guys have any idea on how to do this in a better way?